# Unable to send int array into a function in C

Tags: c

I tried to write a function that performs binary search. the code I wrote is as follows:

```
int binarySearch (int num[], int value, int left, int right)
{
    if (left > right)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int middle = (left+right)/2;
        if (num[middle] = value)
            return middle;
        else
        {
            if (value < num[middle])
                return binarySearch(num, value, left, middle-1);
            else
                return binarySearch(num, value, middle+1, right);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    int num[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int result;
    result = binarySearch(num,6,0,15);
    printf("The result is: %d", result);
}
```

While trying to debug it I found out the num[] array doesn't being send into the function. When I look at the array outside of the function it contains 16 numbers. when I jump into the function with F11 the array that arr[] receives contains only 0. Nothing I try seems to solve it. Does someone understands what goes wrong?

Thank you very much,

Robert

Comment: Are you sure you want to invoke an infinite loop in `while (left < right);`? Are you sure you want to do an assignment, not comparison, in `if (arr[middle] = value)`?

Comment: I don't see an array named `arr`

Comment: It seems odd to convert the function from iterative to recursive, presumably to avoid the infinite loop problem, but transfer the assignment problem (`if (num[middle] = value)`) into the new code.  The `=` is assignment; `==` is equality.  If you're searching for zero, the assignment always 'fails'; otherwise, it always succeeds.  You should make the array parameter `const` so you get told by the compiler when you do assignments to it.

Comment: @CortAmmon The code of the question has been greatly modified.

Comment: What is "F11"? Is that a debugger? Maybe you should get a better debugger then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **binarySearch** function **num** acts as pointer. So, when you debug, it shows only first value (0) pointed by num.

If you want to **pass a single-dimension array as an argument in a function**, you would have to declare a formal parameter in one of following three ways and all three declaration methods produce similar results because each **tells the compiler that an integer pointer is going to be received**.

```
int func(int arr[], ...){
    .
    .
    .
}

int func(int arr[SIZE], ...){
    .
    .
    .
}

int func(int* arr, ...){
    .
    .
    .
}
```

However, by mistake you did an assignment instead of comparison, in if (arr[middle] = value).

Thanks !!!

Comment: Thank you very much! The assignment was the mistake and you made it clear why I see only the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays cannot be sent as function arguments in C. Arguments declared as array are converted to pointers that point at the element of array, according to [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.6.3.

Arrays used in expressions are automatically converted to pointers pointing the first element of the array except for some exceptions such as operands of unary `&` operator and `sizeof` operator, according to N1570 6.3.2.1.

Therefore, the acutual type of `arr` is `int*` and it seems that the debugger recognized only the elemente pointed at directly by the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors that are stopping your code from working.  (e.g. while loop has a ";" ignoring the loop content).

The biggest issue with your code is that you calculated the middle index incorrectly.

**Incorrect:**

```
middle = (left + right) / 2;
```

**Correct:**

```
middle = ((right - left) / 2) + left;
```

You need to subtract to get the actual distance between left and right, then divide by 2 to get the middle.  Then add back to the smaller value to reach the middle between the left and right sides.

**Here is your code with syntax fixed and a mid function to make things easier.**  Enjoy.

```
int mid(int min, int max) {
    return ((max - min) / 2) + min;
}

int binarySearch(int value, int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int middle = mid(left,right);
    while (left < right)
    {
        if (arr[middle] == value)
            return middle;

        if (value < arr[middle])
            middle = mid(left, middle);
        else
            middle = mid(middle, right);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `middle = (left + right) / 2;` is incorrect? This formula will work unless `left` and `right` are large enough to cause overflow, and the two formula made no differencefor all integer in `0 <= left <= right < 1000`. The bigger problem is that the same value may be assigned to `middle` and it may cause an infinite loop. demo: https://ideone.com/Z0j8vO

Comment: MikeCAT: Try a negative left number.

Answer (score -1):

You should just use the `int *` syntax in your function signature.  C will handle this by passing a pointer to the first element of the array.  In C, arrays are not passed like they are in Java or other high-level languages.

Note that you can still use the `[]` operator on a pointer, similarly to an array.  In your example, you can refer to the 2nd element of the array by using this syntax:

```
int x = num[1];  /* get the second element of the num array */
```

This would be the updated function (copied "as is" from the original), with only changes made specific to the array usage:

```
int binarySearch (int *num, int value, int left, int right)
{
    if (left > right)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int middle = (left+right)/2;
        if (num[middle] = value)
            return middle;
        else
        {
            if (value < num[middle])
                return binarySearch(num, value, left, middle-1);
            else
                return binarySearch(num, value, middle+1, right);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    int num[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int result;
    result = binarySearch(num,6,0,15);
    printf("The result is: %d", result);
}
```

One additional thing that you typically need to do is pass the length of the array as a separate argument.  This is so that the function can know how many elements are in the array.  C does not automatically pass the array length the pointer to the first array element, so you have to take care of it manually.

The OP's code does not use the length of the array, so length is not added to that function signature.  However, requiring access to the length of a C array and passing it to a function is so common that it bears an clear example.  Consider this example function to sum the values of an array:

```
int summation_function(int * array, size_t length)
{
    int sum = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (; i < length; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

To call `summation_function`, you can do something like this:

```
int values[] = {1,2,4,8,16,32};
int sum = summation_function(values, sizeof(values)/sizeof(int));

printf("Summation of the values [1,2,4,8,16,32] is %d\n", sum);
```

Note the use of this code in this example:

```
sizeof(num)/sizeof(int)
```

What this does is find the allocated number of bytes in the array (the sizeof(num)) and divide by the number of bytes in an int (the sizeof(int)).  The result is the exact number of elements in the array.  With this, you can avoid hard-coding array lengths.  This code is idiomatic of C array handling, so it becomes second nature to understand it after the first few uses.

Comment: Why is necessary to the length of the array that is not used? also `if (num[middle] = value)` is wrong.

Comment: I had copied the code "as is" from the original, and didn't make any changes except array usage (mentioned right above the code).  I'm in the process of correcting the logic of the code to accommodate the bounds checks necessary to make the code "correct" with regard to its intended usage, and that may take just a bit longer.  Technically, if the length isn't used, you wouldn't need to pass it, but in this case, it's not used because there are bugs in the original code.  I primarily intended to show how arrays in C work in context of the code, not so much to debug the code entirely.

Comment: The part that you have added is not used in the original that is not the original bug.

Comment: Your code does not become an example of use.
It is almost meaningless.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are very correct, sir!  I have completed the changes that I intended to make, and removed the unnecessary `length` parameters from the original.  I added a second example that should actually demonstrate how to calculate and use the array's length.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: "You should just use the `int *` syntax, which is what a C array actually is." - Plain wrong! An array is not  the same as a pointer (or vice-versa). Said that, using array notation for functions parameters makes the code more self-documenting. Even more, if you don't omit the length. That way, without reading the body, you instantly know an array is expected and which parameter is the length. Also this might aid static code checkers to detect array-related flaws in your code.

Comment: And the "natural" type for array indexes is `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: @Olaf Array notation for functions is a misfeature of C that should be avoided. I completely agree with the answer in this regard.  It looks like an array, but isn't, and the language doesn't even support array passing (other than via wrapping an array in a structure). Things that look like swans, but are actually chickens, don't help anyone.

Comment: -1 There are a lot of misconceptions in this answer: a C array is not "actually" a pointer, then you're talking about an 'array pointer' (which would be something like int (*a)[], however what you should be talking about is implicit array to pointer conversion (which is a pointer to the first element of the an array)

Comment: @Kaz: Every C programmer has to be aware of that, so there is no danger. But you work against self-documenting code if you use the pointer notation. Whoever wrote a great bunch of code using tools like Doxygen should appreciate such self-documenting code. Note that with your logic you also had write `f(&array[0])` if you pass an "array" to such a function, because `f(array)` is also missleading. I strongly doubt you use the first form here, so you also rely on the implicit conversion.

Comment: @Olaf The updated example actually uses a size_t instead of an int.  I noticed that while I was editing the post related to the previous comments, so I think that your comment and my update occurred at the same time.  Cheers!

Comment: @MichaelGaskill: That was (one of) the least flaws/faults actually.